# Data type mismatch in criteria expression BUT not always, sometimes work, sometimes not vbnet / access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

It sometimes work, sometimes doesn't, but it updates the database when it works. I don't really know what's the problem anymore, all I'm inputting are numbers

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(cs) 'my database path
Dim add As String = "INSERT INTO tblGrades ([Semester], [Subject], [Prelim], [Midterm], [Final], [StudentID]) VALUES (@Semester, @Subject, @Prelim, @Midterm, @Final, @StudentID)"

        If cmbSemester.Text = Nothing Or cmbSubject.Text = Nothing Or txtboxPrelim.Text = Nothing Or txtboxMidterm.Text = Nothing Or txtboxFinals.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Fill up the empty box", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Missing")

        Else
            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(add, conn)
            'Gives a parameter for database column name
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Semester", CType(cmbSemester.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Subject", CType(cmbSubject.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Prelim", CType(txtboxPrelim.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Midterm", CType(txtboxMidterm.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Final", CType(txtboxFinals.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("StudentID", CType(txtboxStudentID.Text, String)))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Add Grades?", "Add Grade Info", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

            Me.Controls.Clear()
            InitializeComponent()
            FormModifyGrades_Load(e, e)
            Refresh()
        End If

    End Sub
```

Data types are string both in codes and in access, since I only need to type the number without any computation, help please, been stuck for hours.

Comment: Not easy. Debug your data - find differences between the records that succeed and those that fails.

Comment: What are the data types of each of your columns?

Comment: Your emptiness checks look odd.  I would normally expect `Nothing` checks to be of the form `Is Nothing` (or for the negative, `IsNot Nothing`).  With strings, I will often use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` (and that seems more appropriate for your context).  I don't know if that has anything to do with your error, though.

Comment: What's the point of "converting" the `Text` of a control, which is type `String`, to a `String`?

Comment: @Craig, with a `String`, testing `x Is Nothing` will only match a null reference whereas testing `x = Nothing` will match a null reference or an empty `String`. The former is reference equality and the latter is value equality. `String` is one of the few classes that supports value equality, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Got it, thanks.  So it's basically equivalent to calling `String.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check a few things.

1. It seems that you need to find the exact error point by putting a try/catch statement.
2. You should check the DB Table column type.
   ex) input length and attributes
3. It seems that you should also check the input value in the TextBox. It looks like you need a length check rather than a Notthing check.

   TextBox.text = "" (O)

   TextBox.Text = Nothing (X) No.